# HTML: How to use a div (or something) as a substitute for a file

Tags: html

Currently I have 2 HTML files, MainSection.html and MainHeader.html

At the top of MainSection.html there is a tag called like this:

```
<ui-accord ui-header="MainHeader">
```

This uses the content in MainHeader.html and it works as the value.

I want to merge these files into one, I tried putting the contents of MainHeader.html into a div and then using the id as the value for ui-header but it does not work properly - ui-header seems to work only for files.

Is there someway to store the div as a file - even though it's not in its own file?

Comment: What is `ui-accord`?

Comment: it is a custom HTML element that I am using, the ui-header attribute works by taking in a different file

Comment: The attribute ui-header accepts a HTML, string or template entry

Comment: Are you using any JS framework? Give code for `ui-accord`.